# Show that the limit is divergent

Tags: limits

I want to calculate the following limit:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} Ax^{b} \cos(c \log(x)),
$$
where $A$, $b>0$ and $c$ are some constants.

I suppose that the function $Ax^{b} \cos(c \log(x))$ is not convergent when $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Firstly, I think I can show that 
$$
A\cos(c \log(x))
$$
is not convergent when $x\rightarrow \infty$.

For this purpose I use two different subsequences and show that the limit converges to different values:

1. $x = e^{\frac{2n}{c}\pi}$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} A \cos(c \log(x)) = A$.
2. $x = e^{\frac{2n+1}{c}\pi}$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} A \cos(c \log(x)) = -A$.

Of course, I assumed that $A\neq 0$.

Moreover, I know that:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{b} = +\infty
$$
for $b>0$

Then, I claim that:
$$
Ax^{b} \cos(c \log(x))
$$
is not convergent when $x\rightarrow \infty$, because it is a product of a function which is not convergent and a function which has a limit equal to $\infty$.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: What is your definition of divergent? (Not convergent or limit infinite?)

Comment: You are right, I wrote it not precisely. I corrected what do I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is correct, we can simply note that since $|c \log x|\to \infty$ is continuos

- $\cos(c \log(x))$ oscillates from $-1$ and $1$

and

- $|Ax^{b}|\to \infty$

then

- $Ax^{b} \cos(c \log(x))$ doesn't converges ("*oscillates between*" $+\infty$ and $-\infty$)

Comment: Thank you! If I will assume now that $b<0$ and consider convergence: $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ can I draw the same conclusion, that is: that the function $Ax^b cos(c\log(b)$ does not converges for $b<0$ when $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$?

Comment: If $x^b\to 0$ you can easily conclude for convergence by squeeze theorem.

Comment: But if b<0, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}x^b = + \infty$

Comment: @JonasAl-Hadad Ops sorry I was thinking to the case $\to \infty$! Yes of course in this case the same result holds since $\cos$ oscillates and the other part diverges (or doesn't tend to zero).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $Ax^b$ diverges is unimportant. It suffices to say that the function is alternating and doesn't tend to $0$.

Comment: You are right of course!